# сохранить фрагмент в activity при повороте

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

у меня есть MainActivity в разметке которого есть FrameLayout (контейнер для фрагментов).
при запуске Activity я загружаю в этот контейнер фрагмент. на фрагменте RecyclerView и  CardView дальше по клику на елемент в этот же контейнер загружаю новый фрагмент с подробным описанием.
все работает но при смене ориентации устройства второй фрагмент теряется и показывается только первый с списком.
Это потому что первый фрагмент я загружаю в контейнер в методе onCreate и при пересоздании активити он загружается, а второй фрагмент загружается только по клику на елемент обработка клика происходит в фрагменте как мне решить эту проблему?

код активити

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragment = new FragmentList();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.conteiner, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

код загрузки второго фрагмента

```
  public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            Item item = itemArrayList.get(position);
            Fragment fullArticleFragment = new FullArticleFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("url", item.getLink());
            fullArticleFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.conteiner, fullArticleFragment).commit();

        }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

При повороте пересоздается не только активити но и все фрагменты, но если вы при пересоздании активити и сами создаете фрагмент, то он заменяет автопересозданный с восстановленным состоянием на новый с начальным состоянием. Вам не нужно вручную пересоздавать свой фрагмент в onCreate активити если идет восстановление состояния, для этого надо добавить условие:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragment = new FragmentList();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.conteiner, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

И кстати в бэк стек начальный фрагмент вы зачем добавляете? Что бы при нажатии назад он удалялся с активити и та оставалась пустой?)

Ещё как вариант если у вас разметка экрана на активити и фрагментах не зависит от ориентации экрана, то можете просто отключить пересоздание активити при смене ориентации добавив в описание активити в манифесте атрибут `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"`

Comment: Подскажите,когда мы делаем поворот экрана - активность пересоздается,соответственно и вьюхи тоже пересоздаются?

Comment: @Tony если ты их никуда не сохранил и просто вызываешь setContentView, то тоже конечно пересоздаются.

Comment: А куда их можно сохранить?))

Comment: @Tony лучше никуда их не сохранять, потом только больше проблем огребете