# Как правильно сохранить состояние фрагмента при повороте экрана

Tags: android, android-fragment, textview

Создаю обычный проект "navigation drawer activity" в android studio.При запуске сразу добавляю фрагмент в контейнер. Происходят определенные вычисления, результаты которых отображаются в TextView фрагмента. Так вот при первом повороте экрана приложение восстанавливает состояние TextView фрагмента без каких-либо проблем. Если я делаю второй поворот экрана - приложение вылетает. 
Описание ошибки и код прикладываю ниже. Конечно пытался найти решение самостоятельно, но не получается. Буду признателен за помощь.

Код MainAcitivity

```
FragmentFirst fFragmentFirst;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
String TAG = "myLogs";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ......
     fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
     fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     fFragmentFirst = new FragmentFirst();

    if(savedInstanceState==null){
        Log.d(TAG,"savedInstanceState activity == null");
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.conteiner, fFragmentFirst).commit();
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG,"savedInstanceState activity != null");
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.conteiner,fragmentManager.getFragment(savedInstanceState,"fFragmentFirst")).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    fragmentManager.putFragment(outState, "fFragmentFirst", fFragmentFirst);
}
```

Код фрагмента

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putString("usd_save",tv_usd.getText().toString());
    savedInstanceState.putString("euro_save", tv_euro.getText().toString());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first,container,false);
    tv_usd = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_usd);
    tv_euro = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_euro);
    return view; 
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Log.d(TAG,"If savedInstanceState fragment == null");
        USD findUSD = new USD();
        findUSD.execute();
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG,"If savedInstanceState != null");           
        tv_usd.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("usd_save"));
        tv_euro.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("euro_save"));
    }
}
```

Ошибка

```
10-19 17:56:10.546 19019-19019/samples.com.money5saxparser E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: samples.com.money5saxparser, PID: 19019
                                                                         Theme: themes:{}
                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment FragmentFirst{fb7021f} is not currently in the FragmentManager
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.putFragment(FragmentManager.java:674)
                                                                             at samples.com.money5saxparser.MainActivity.onSaveInstanceState(MainActivity.java:70)
```

Comment: Данная тема помогла мне " [сохранить фрагмент в activity при повороте] "(http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/578408/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B2-activity-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Зачем вам эти извращения с `savedInstanceState`, при использовании фрагментов?Одна из замечательнейших причин их использовать - это `setRetainInstance(true)` в методе `onCreateView`.

Данный метод говорит, чтобы фрагмент при уничтожении оставлял свое состояние, и убивал только внешнее представление, как только он открепляется от активити и прикрепляется заново - то данные берутся из сохраненного состояния.

Comment: Стоит дополнить, что `setRetainInstance(true)` – это не универсальное решение. В случае использования `setRetainInstance(true)` и наличия во фрагменте ссылок на что-либо, что будет пересоздано при изменении конфигурации устройства (в частности, при повороте экрана) – все будет очень плохо.

Comment: Добавление setRetainInstance(true) проблему не решает. Если удаляю savedInstanceState, то каждый раз при повороте начинается выполнение

Comment: @post_zeew то есть если я имею поле с адаптером для ресайклера в фрагменте, то он при повороте начнет чудить?

Comment: USD findUSD = new USD();
findUSD.execute();

Comment: @Asgard, Сразу прям точно не скажу. Это скорее всего будет зависеть от того, что Вы храните в адаптере.

Comment: Вот [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15066467) можно почитать подробнее про целесообразность использования `setRetainInstance(true)`.